# OpenCL POCL + asan or valgrind

Tags: c++, opencl, address-sanitizer, pocl

I am trying to debug my OpenCL kernel. I think, the error is in wrong memory allocation. So, I'am looking for a way to detect it.

Long story short, could I just run OpenCL kernel on POCL platform and check it with well-known instruments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Oclgrind should give more helpful error messages, but also pocl's debug symbol support should again work in master. Thus, valgrind and gdb should now be able to identify OpenCL C line numbers better.

There's also a new env POCL_EXTRA_BUILD_FLAGS in pocl master:

"Adds the contents of the environment variable to all clBuildProgram() calls.
E.g. POCL_EXTRA_BUILD_FLAGS="-g -cl-opt-disable" can be useful for force
adding debug data all the built kernels to help debugging kernel issues
with tools such as gdb or valgrind."

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. However, there is also tool called `Oclgrind` designed just for that: https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind